# Parse Multiline JSON with Arrays using grok in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-grok

Hi this is my first time using Kibana.
I am trying to parse the below input file to logstash and put it to elastic search for use in Kibana.

```
{
  "ASRtest": {
    "ASRHDR": "This is asr HDR",
    "ASRTestType": "DevTest",
    "Scenario": [
      {
        "ScenarioNumber": 1,
        "ScenarioName": "HTTP Validation",
        "ScenarioDescription": "Validate if the API alows access over HTTP",
        "ScExecutionStatus": "Execution Complete",
        "ScenarioStatus": "In-Complete",
        "ScenarioSeverity": false,
        "TestCase": [
          {
            "TestCaseNumber": 1,
            "TestCaseName": "HTTP Validation - using POST method ",
            "TcExecutionStatus": "Execution Error",
            "TcStatus": "NA",
            "TcSeverity": "NA"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ScenarioNumber": 2,
        "ScenarioName": "Server Platform/Version Disclosure",
        "ScenarioDescription": "Validate if API disclose server information",
        "ScExecutionStatus": "Execution Complete",
        "ScenarioStatus": "Failure",
        "ScenarioSeverity": "Medium",
        "TestCase": [
          {
            "TestCaseNumber": 1,
            "TestCaseName": "Server Platform/Version Disclosure - using POST method ",
            "TcExecutionStatus": "Executed Successfully",
            "TcStatus": "Failure",
            "TcSeverity": "Medium"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want all the fields in the input to be available for the dashboard charts. Could anyone explain how to parse this multiline JSON file to logstash ==> elasticsearch.
I tried a sample config file but I wa not able to produce the desired output.

Comment: if you could show your sample config?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to use [multiline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html#plugins-codecs-multiline) [codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-codec) which could ideally  allow joining of multiline messages from files into a single event. The `input` could look something like this:

```
input 
{   
    file 
    {
        codec => multiline
        {
            pattern => '^\{'
            negate => true
            what => previous                
        }
        path => ["path to your json file/.json"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        exclude => "*.gz"
    }
}
```

[This](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-parse-the-multiline-json-file-through-logstash/60843/7) thread and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713531/logstash-parse-complicated-multiline-json-from-log-file-into-elasticsearch) could be useful. Hope it helps!

Comment: Do I need to have any filters to this config file. I actually need all the fields in this JSON file. Sorry this may be a dump question but most of the examples have some filtering when used with codec.

Comment: Another question is do I need to have an index statement in my output?

Comment: @Anoop yes you might need to have a filter, in order to retrieve all the necessary fields you need. I've just shown only the input section. 
Well to answer your second Q, what do you mean by index statement?

Comment: Hi Darth. We had the input section with us but it was the filter section that we were struggling with We used gsub, mutant and some other options but all of them did not work. Another issue that we were having was that logstash will not load the file when we start it with this configuration. With Index I ment the index command that we use in the output section to create and index.

Comment: Sorry I did not explain what I mean when I say it did not load, Logstash started with the multiline codec and processed it. But for some reason we did not see the data in elastic search. we tried to create an index too but that was also processed successfully but did not create anything in elastic search.

Comment: @Anoop If you could post your whole config in your question ?